# UNIX: Finding lines

Tags: regex, bash, unix, ksh

I need to write a small script, which it find lines according to a regular expression (for example "^folder#) and it will write the number of lines where it matchs.

My idea is, that I will use "find", then delete all slash and then use grep with a regular expression. 
I don't know why it doesn't work. Could you give some advice how to improve, or how I should find that lines with another function?

In

```
./example
./folder/.DS_Store
./folder/file.png
```

---

Out

```
2: ./folder/.DS_Store
3: ./folder/file.png
```

---

```
IGN="^folder$"

find . -type f | sed -e "s/\// /g" | grep -n "${IGN}"
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the slashes? Maybe `wc` is what you are looking for, check the `-l` option.

Comment: You don't want `"^folder$"` . Try just `IGN="folder"` or to be super-explicit, try`="/folder/"`. Good luck.

Comment: Well, because I thought that "^folder#" means that before and after that word is nothing - that's the reason why I use space.

Comment: shellter: it is a task, that I need to find a folder by using "^folder$". :)

Comment: `^` means "start of line" and `$` means "end of line". `#` just means "#".

Comment: You should replace `^` and `$` by `\b`.

Comment: @user3463055 Another note "nothing" is not defined in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried

```
IGN="^folder$"
find . -type f | sed -e "s/\// /g" | grep -n "${IGN}"
```

This script isn't working since IGN looks for start-of-line, not start-of-word.
You can make lines from the parts of your paths with

```
IGN="^folder$"
find . -type f | tr -s "/" "\n" | grep -n "${IGN}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to use `^folder$` pattern but you want to get output like:

> ```
> 2: ./folder/.DS_Store
> 3: ./folder/file.png
> ```

These two requests contradict each other. A line like `./folder/.DS_Store` cannot match pattern `^folder$` because the line doesn't start with "folder" and doesn't end with "folder".

To get the output you describe you need to change the pattern used with `grep` to `^\./folder/`